# Arduino gets false triggers due to compressor switching on/off?

Tags: arduino, switches, signal, noise

I'm working on controlling a rotating arm with a mounted camera through a DC motor and limit switches inside a proofing chamber.

Whenever the compressor of the chamber turns on/off, false limit switch triggers occur to the Arduino.
The limit switches are connected *normally-opened* through a pull-up circuit.
The arm rotation works totally fine according to my code except for the moments when the compressor switches on or off.

What's causing this and how could it be solved?

Comment: Perhaps your arduino needs some sort of shield (pun intended)?

Comment: If the limit switches are for safety, then they should be independent of the Arduino.  EG: they would directly interrupt the motor supply. (May require switches with more current capacity and freewheeling diodes.)

Answer (score 14):

This is almost certainly noise, probably due to several design problems:

High impedance.  A passively pulled up signal has the impedance of the pullup in the quiescient state.  In a noisy environment, this pullup needs to be low, or passively floating lines avoided altogether.

No shielding.

Bad overall system grounding strategy.  Since you mentioned "arduino", possibly even no overall system grounding strategy.

Bad firmware.  Short glitches on mechanically switched lines should be expected.

Comment: Always debounce. But this is sometimes tricky on limit switches for high speed (or inertia) moving parts.

Answer (score 1):

As Olin Lathrop points out, electrical noise is the problem. There are three things you really want to do:

1) Use capacitors where long wires enter. This will prevent electrical noise picked up by the wires from interfering with the Arduino. You can also use capacitors close to the Arduino.

2) Use optical isolation and higher flows of current that are less susceptible to noise. So instead of just using a pull up for the switch, have the switch close a circuit with a series resistor that illuminates an LED that shines on a photodiode or phototransistor. Optoisolators cost a few pennies and do exactly what you need. Here's the spec sheet for one - [link](http://www.vishay.com/docs/83657/mct5211.pdf). Isolate both inputs and outputs if you can.

3) Route noisy wires away from sensitive areas. Keep the lines that go outside the enclosure as far from the Arduino as you can. For example, if you use more than one optoisolator, line them up so that the Arduino sides are near the Arduino and the side that connects to the outside world is away from it.